# How to evenly scale down measurements in a recipe to meet certain weight by gram?

Tags: statistics, ratio

Very new to this.

I have a recipe that has 9 ingredients, with varying weights that produces a total of 191grams.

For example:

```
ingredient   weight(grams)
a              15            
b              10
c              5
d              5
e              145
f              8 
g              1
h              1
i              1
```

I need to scale down the weights of all these ingredients, evenly, to 135 grams.

How do I calculate a ratio for all the ingredients that evenly scales down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply each weight by $135/191.$

Comment: perfect thank you!

Comment: @RustyShackleford You're welcome.